# Backbone: event lost in re-render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have *super-View* who is in charge of rendering *sub-Views*. When I *re-render* the *super-View* all the events in the *sub-Views* are lost.

This is an example:

```
var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click": "click"
    },

    click: function(){
        console.log( "click!" );
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( "click me" );
        return this;
    }
});

var Composer = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.subView = new SubView();
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.subView.render().el );             
    }
});


var composer = new Composer({el: $('#composer')});
composer.render();
```

When I click in the *click me* div the event is triggered. If I execute `composer.render()` again everything looks pretty the same but the *click event* is not triggered any more.

Check the [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/6frH6/).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

When you do this:

```
this.$el.html( this.subView.render().el );
```

You're effectively saying this:

```
this.$el.empty();
this.$el.append( this.subView.render().el );
```

and [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) kills the events on everything inside `this.$el`:

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves.

So you lose the `delegate` call that binds events on `this.subView` and the `SubView#render` won't rebind them.

You need to slip a `this.subView.delegateEvents()` call into `this.$el.html()` but you need it to happen after the `empty()`. You could do it like this:

```
render: function(){
    console.log( "Composer.render" );
    this.$el.empty();
    this.subView.delegateEvents();
    this.$el.append( this.subView.render().el );             
    return this;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/57maA/1/

Or like this:

```
render: function(){
    console.log( "Composer.render" );
    this.$el.html( this.subView.render().el );             
    this.subView.delegateEvents();
    return this;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4qrRa/

Or you could [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) and re-create the `this.subView` when rendering and sidestep the problem that way (but this might cause other problems...).

Comment: I would never have found it by my self. It is a little insane :/. Thanks @mu

Comment: @fguillen: I had to track down something similar and I think it involved a trip through the jQuery source and a fair bit of experimentation. The effort has permanently burned this into my memory.

Comment: This has led me to proper direction to fix my issue. Thank you @muistooshort

Comment: @muistooshort similar problem but delegateEvents is not helping. http://jsfiddle.net/ismusidhu/kt9zr5z9/7/

Comment: @IsmailS: What does your `render` call do to the view's `this.img` property? Here's a hint: it works if you use `this.$('#abc')` instead of trying to cache `this.img`. Toss a `console.log('clicked')` in your click handler and you'll see that you don't have an event problem.

Answer (score 11):

There's a simpler solution here that doesn't blow away the event registrations in the first place: `jQuery.detach()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ypG8U/1/

```
this.subView.render().$el.detach().appendTo( this.$el );
```

This variation is probably preferable for performance reasons though:

http://jsfiddle.net/ypG8U/2/

```
this.subView.$el.detach();

this.subView.render().$el.appendTo( this.$el );

// or

this.$el.append( this.subView.render().el );
```

Obviously this is a simplification that matches the example, where the sub view is the only content of the parent. If that was really the case, you could just re-render the sub view. If there were other content you could do something like:

```
var children = array[];

this.$el.children().detach();

children.push( subView.render().el );

// ...

this.$el.append( children );
```

or

```
_( this.subViews ).each( function ( subView ) {

  subView.$el.detach();

} );

// ...
```

Also, in your original code, and repeated in @mu's answer, a DOM object is passed to `jQuery.html()`, but that method is only documented as accepting strings of HTML:

```
this.$el.html( this.subView.render().el );
```

Documented signature for `jQuery.html()`:

```
.html( htmlString )
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Comment: Very interesting, _simpler solution_ is not the world that I'd use but it is really good to know. Thanks

Comment: I guess whether it's "simpler" from the perspective of authoring the view classes is debatable. I think it's probably more efficient though since you're retaining the event listener registrations instead of re-applying them each time. If it's possible that you'll also have data stored with the element via `jQuery.data()` that you want to preserve upon re-rendering, that's a consideration too, as `detach()` will preserve the data without additional code.

Answer (score 0):

When using `$(el).empty()` it removes all the child elements in the selected element **AND removes ALL** the **events** (and data) that are **bound to any (child) elements** inside of the selected element (`el`).

To **keep the events bound to** the **child elements**, but still remove the child elements, use:

`$(el).children().detach();` instead of `$(.el).empty();`

This will allow your view to rerender successfully with the events still bound and working.

Comment: Please see these for further reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7417078/2728686 and http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/empty-vs-remove-vs-detach-jquery.html