# Backbone.View events not being bound

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Am trying to resolve the backbone ghost view in my application, which am doing by giving all my views a close method, which removes the view from the DOM.
My views are being rendered in the main div tag after loading the view as an external template. 
Before i discovered the ghost view issue, the event were being fired twice and it seems they are not being bound at all.

Comment: and your question/problem is?

Comment: the events are not bound to the view

Comment: We would appreciate if you would make the effort to not just copy/paste your application code but re-create the issue in the most minimal code example.

Comment: @fguillen's advice is good - because in the process of minimizing your problem, you may actually solve it yourself.  :)

Comment: Can be this your case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028835/backbone-event-lost-in-re-render Anyhow too much code is bad, none code is also bad, try to reproduce the issue in a very minimal version of code. It took to me several hours to come up with the example code of this link. Isolate the code that produces the issue is a work, it is a work that has to be done by who is asking for help.