# Chaplin no context after template rerender

Tags: backbone.js, chaplinjs

I'm trying to have a view which can have interchangable templates. So clicking on one of the checkbox rerenders the view. this in fact is happening . but after the view has rerenderd and show the new template correctly im loosing the context and all click bound to this view don't work anymore. http://pastebin.com/bFJ5Yuer

```
View = require 'views/base/view'
template = require 'views/templates/list_view_a'

module.exports = class OfferListView extends View
autoRender: true
container: "[data-role='content']"
containerMethod: 'html'
   initialize: ->
    super
    @template = template
    #views
    @delegate 'change', '#list_view_a', @change_list_view
    @delegate 'change', '#list_view_b', @change_list_view
    @delegate 'change', '#list_view_c', @change_list_view
    @delegate 'click',  @click_ev

change_list_view: (event) =>
    console.log('change')
    @template = require 'views/templates/' + event.target.id
    @render()

click_ev: =>
    console.log('click')

getTemplateData: =>
    @collection.toJSON()
```

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the call to `@render` in `change_list_view` is wiping out the element that the events are bound to in the `initialize` method.

If you must re-render the view (like if you are changing the template) then you will just have to add a call to `@delegateEvents` below the `@render` call in `change_list_view`.

**UPDATE**

If you wanted to switch to a subview method, you could probably get rid of that second call to render.  Something like this:

```
# snipped all the outer require js stuff

class InnerViewBase extends Chaplin.View # Or whatever your base view is
  autoRender: true
  container: "#innerViewContainer"
  containerMethod: "html"

  initialize: (templateName) ->
    @template = require templateName

    super

class ListViewA extends InnerViewBase
  initialize: ->
    super "views/templates/list_view_a"

    # Do any event handlers in here, instead of the outer view
    # @delegate 'click',  @click_ev

class ListViewB extends InnerViewBase
  initialize: ->
    super "views/templates/list_view_b"

class ListViewC extends InnerViewBase
  initialize: ->
    super "views/templates/list_view_b"

class OfferListView extends View
  autoRender: true
  container: "[data-role='content']"
  containerMethod: 'html'

  initialize: ->
    super
    @template = template

    #views
    # Consider changing these three id subscriptions to a class
    @delegate 'change', '#list_view_a', @change_list_view
    @delegate 'change', '#list_view_b', @change_list_view
    @delegate 'change', '#list_view_c', @change_list_view
    @delegate 'click',  @click_ev

  afterRender: ->
    # Add a default ListView here if you want
    # @subview "ListView", new ListViewA

  change_list_view: (event) =>
    console.log('change')

    # Make a hacky looking map to the subview constructors
    viewNames = 
      "list_view_a": ListViewA
      "list_view_b": ListViewB
      "list_view_c": ListViewC

    @subview "ListView", new viewNames[event.target.id]

  click_ev: =>
    console.log('click')

  getTemplateData: =>
    @collection.toJSON()
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to @delegateEvents didn't do the trick. But thanks for pointing me in a right direction. 
This was helpful as well. [Backbone: event lost in re-render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028835/backbone-event-lost-in-re-render)

mind my wrong indentation

```
View = require 'views/base/view'
template = require 'views/templates/list_view_a'

module.exports = class OfferListView extends View
autoRender: true
container: "[data-role='content']"
containerMethod: 'html'
template: template
initialize: (options) ->
    super        
    #views
change_list_view: (event) =>
    @template = require 'views/templates/' + event.target.id
    @render()

initEvents: =>
    @delegate 'change', '#list_view_a', @change_list_view
    @delegate 'change', '#list_view_b', @change_list_view
    @delegate 'change', '#list_view_c', @change_list_view
    @delegate 'click',  @click_ev
click_ev: ->
    console.log('click')
render: =>
    super

afterRender: =>
    super
    @initEvents()
```